# Linux grep command to match multiple patterns with multiple options

Tags: regex, linux

How can i use grep command to match multiple patterns with multiple options i.e.

```
cat example.txt | grep -A 2 -e "test1" -A 5 -e "test2"
```

The main goal is that 2 lines after test1 or 5 lines after test2 are printed but when i am using the above grep command, it is printing 5 lines after both patterns.

Comment: `grep` has no support for this; you need to postprocess its output, or write a simple Awk script instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a Perl one-liner to do this.

```
perl -ne 'print if (/test1/ and $p=2)||(/test2/ and $p=5)..not $p--' example.txt
```